# Substituting milk with whipping cream

Tags: substitutions

I'm making a corn bake in the crock pot that calls for 1 1/2 cups of milk. How much whipping cream would I use?

Comment: Thanks for posting this as a question! Could you include the recipe in your question? You can use the "edit" button to do so.

Comment: What is a crock pot? (and a corn bake, but we will get that from the recipe).

Comment: The amount of fat is about 5:1, but cream has no sugar in it so you may wish to adjust that. Why aren't you using milk?

Comment: @MarcLuxen [Crock pot](https://www.google.com/search?q=crock+pot) is a brand name for slow cooker, commonly used as a synonym in American English.

Comment: @MarcLuxen not exactly. A pot with integrated heating and and often a timer, used for slow cooking / simmering at low temperatures for many hours.

Comment: I see. Is there any culinary difference between this and a pan on a hob?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Make the dish richer, or are you out of milk?

Comment: @MarcLuxen - "Crock Pot" is sort of a proprietary name for a [slow cooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_cooker).  It is generally used to cook things...  well...  slowly, over low heat.  It excels at low temperature, long duration cooking, and isn't very good for anything else.  People often use them when they are busy and can't stick around to keep an eye on the hob (stove) while the food is cooking.  You can turn them on, go run errands, and come home to a finished dish/meal.  You COULD do this with a hob, but it would be somewhat riskier.

Comment: Right. Well, I will stick to my cast-iron Creuset. Too many gadgets in my kitchen already!

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer says, there is an enormous difference between milk and cream.

However, it is *possible* to reach a rough substitute for milk by mixing your cream with an equal amount of water by volume - in your case, 3/4 cream and 3/4 cup water.

It won't be exactly the same (the fat content will still be substantially higher than it would be if you used milk, and if you do a taste test, comparing the flavor of whole milk to a 50/50 cream/water mix, you'll see that the flavor is also very different), but it *should* work.

However, there is a chance that the higher fat content will lead to the sauce breaking, so if you want to be 100% sure of success, go get some milk.  If you're willing to gamble a bit, try diluting the cream.

Answer (score 1):

Whole milk is 3.5 % fat.

Whipping Cream is 35 % fat.

That's a big difference.

Unless there's a another fat in your recipe that you can reduce, I don't see that you can substitute cream for milk without completely changing the recipe.

Comment: The recipe greatly affects whether the substitution is possible... many sauces, for example, will work just fine, they'll simply be much richer... without knowing the recipe, it's not really possible to answer.